# Determine whether matrix is sparse?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix. I want to know it whether sparse or not.  Is there any function in matlab to evaluate that property? I tried to used `issparse` function, but it always returns `0`(not sparse). For example, my matrix `(27 by 27)` is

```
A=
  [ 1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
    250 243 247 245 244 244 244 122 61  144 72  36  18  9   4   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    151 197 236 118 181 212 106 53  26  13  136 68  34  17  8   4   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    24  12  6   3   143 201 234 117 180 90  45  152 76  38  19  9   4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    18  9   138 69  172 86  165 220 224 112 56  28  128 64  32  16  8   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
    27  131 207 103 189 94  47  153 194 239 119 59  29  128 64  32  16  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
    44  22  133 204 232 116 58  147 199 237 248 124 62  31  129 64  32  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
    238 119 181 90  45  152 76  38  19  135 205 232 116 58  29  128 64  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
    48  24  12  6   3   143 201 100 50  25  130 207 233 116 58  29  128 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    168 84  42  21  132 66  33  158 79  39  19  135 205 232 116 58  29  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
    235 117 58  29  128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1   142 201 234 117 58  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
    0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0]
```

This is figure for above matrix

[image]

Comment: [`issparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/issparse.html) checks to see if a matrix was created using the `sparse` class.  It doesn't assess the sparsity of a matrix.

Comment: So, Has any function to determine matrix whether sparse or not?

Comment: How sparse is sparse for your purposes?

Comment: Sparse matrix has some fast computation than normal matrix. I want to develop a algorithm for sparse matrix, However, firstly, i must check it is sparse or not

Comment: Sparse is not a uniquely defined concept. Tell us what your algorithm exactly needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seemingly easy question is quite difficult to answer.  There is actually no known standard that determines whether a matrix is sparse or full.

However, the most common measure I know is to measure a matrix's [sparsity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).  This is simply the fraction of the total number of zeroes over the total number of elements.  If this exceeds some sensible threshold, then you could say that the matrix is sparse.

If you're given the matrix `A`, perhaps something like this:

```
sparsity = (numel(A) - nnz(A)) / numel(A);
```

[`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) determines the total number of elements in the matrix `A` and [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) determines the total number of non-zero elements.  Therefore, `numel(A) - nnz(A)` should give you the total number of zero elements.

So, going with the threshold idea, this is what I was talking about:

```
is_sparse = sparsity > tol;
```

`tol` would be a fraction from `[0,1]`, so something like `0.75` could work. This would mean that if 75% of your matrix consisted of zeroes, this could be a sparse matrix. It's all heuristic though.  Choose a threshold that you think makes the most sense.

Comment: Have any paper to show tol is more than 0.75? Because when we write the paper, we want to show it is sparse or not. We must cite a standard or paper. Thank rayryeng

Comment: There is no paper.  It's all heuristic as I said.

Comment: @user8264 How sparse is "sparse" depends on the matrix. From WolframMathWorld: "The number of zeros a matrix needs in order to be considered "sparse" depends on the structure of the matrix and the desired operations to perform on it. For example, a randomly generated sparse n×n matrix with cn entries scattered randomly throughout the matrix is not sparse in the sense of Wilkinson (for direct methods) since it takes O(n^3) time to factor (with high probability and for large enough c; Gilbert et al. 1992)." http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SparseMatrix.html

Comment: Thank ohruunuruus for this info. Actually, my matrix is created by special rule (not random). Hence, I hope that it will be sparse

Comment: @user8264 consider the fact that Matlab uses extra `nnz` + number of columns memory to represent a sparse matrix, So if `numel(A) - nnz(A) < nnz(A) + size(A,2)` then it is more memory-efficient to store it as `sparse` in Matlab.

Comment: Thank Shai, .For above matrix, numel(A) - nnz(A) < nnz(A) + size(A,2) return 0 that means it is not sparse. I increase size to 1000, it still returns 0, while rayryeng method return sparse matrix, What is mistake?

Comment: @user8264 - There is no mistake.  Just that the definitions are different.  Remember, it's all heuristic.  There is no gold standard that defines whether a matrix is sparse or not... so one definition may tell you it's sparse while the other doesn't.  I can't think of any definitions that would work in all cases... so you may need to go back and ask yourself why you want to classify whether the matrix is sparse.